# When I add decimal value into always encrypted database it shows error

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search, hibernate-validator, hibernate-ogm, hibernate-tools

**This is main Class Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml");
                EmployeeService employeeService = context.getBean(EmployeeService.class);
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                if(emp.getHdEmpId()==0) {
                    emp.setTxtaEmployeeAddress("abcde");
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeEmail("abcd@localmail.com");
                    emp.setChkHobby("cricket");
                    emp.setRdGender("Male");
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeName("sumit");
                    emp.setTxtEmployeePhone("451254");
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeSalary("100");
                    emp.setSelEmployeeCountry("India");
                    emp.setHdActive(true);
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeTinyIntValue((short)1);
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeIntegerValue(11111);
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeTotalSalary(45454.56556);
                    BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal("12.36");
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeMobile(bd);
                    emp.setTxtEmployeeEmp4(new Long("7845784575"));
                    employeeService.addEmployee(emp);
                }
```

**Model Class**

```
package com.eptl.spring4hibernate4demo.employee.model;

        import java.math.BigDecimal;
        import java.sql.Types;

        import javax.persistence.Column;
        import javax.persistence.Convert;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.Table;

        import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
        import org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType;

        @Entity
        @Table(name="Emp")
        public class Employee {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name="id")
            private int hdEmpId;

            @Column(name="name")
            private String txtEmployeeName;

            @Column(name="phone")
            private String txtEmployeePhone;

            @Column(name="salary")
            private String txtEmployeeSalary;

            @Column(name="email")
            private String txtEmployeeEmail;

            @Column(name="address")
            private String txtaEmployeeAddress;

            @Column(name="gender")
            private String rdGender;

            @Column(name="country")
            private String selEmployeeCountry;

            @Column(name="hobbies")
            private String chkHobby;

            @Column(name="isActive")
            private boolean hdActive;

            @Column(name="Mobile",precision=18,scale=5,columnDefinition="decimal(18,5)")
            @Type(type = "big_decimal")
            private BigDecimal txtEmployeeMobile;

            @Column(name="totalSalary")
            private Double txtEmployeeTotalSalary;

            @Column(name="emp1")
            private Integer txtEmployeeIntegerValue;

            @Column(name="emp2")
            private Short txtEmployeeTinyIntValue;

            @Column(name="emp4")
            private Long txtEmployeeEmp4;

            @Column(precision=18,scale=5)
            public BigDecimal getTxtEmployeeMobile() {
                return txtEmployeeMobile;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeMobile(BigDecimal txtEmployeeMobile) {
                this.txtEmployeeMobile = txtEmployeeMobile;
            }

            public Long getTxtEmployeeEmp4() {
                return txtEmployeeEmp4;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeEmp4(Long txtEmployeeEmp4) {
                this.txtEmployeeEmp4 = txtEmployeeEmp4;
            }

            public int getHdEmpId() {
                return hdEmpId;
            }

            public void setHdEmpId(int hdEmpId) {
                this.hdEmpId = hdEmpId;
            }

            public String getTxtEmployeeName() {
                return txtEmployeeName;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeName(String txtEmployeeName) {
                this.txtEmployeeName = txtEmployeeName;
            }

            public String getTxtEmployeePhone() {
                return txtEmployeePhone;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeePhone(String txtEmployeePhone) {
                this.txtEmployeePhone = txtEmployeePhone;
            }

            public String getTxtEmployeeSalary() {
                return txtEmployeeSalary;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeSalary(String txtEmployeeSalary) {
                this.txtEmployeeSalary = txtEmployeeSalary;
            }

            public String getTxtEmployeeEmail() {
                return txtEmployeeEmail;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeEmail(String txtEmployeeEmail) {
                this.txtEmployeeEmail = txtEmployeeEmail;
            }

            public String getTxtaEmployeeAddress() {
                return txtaEmployeeAddress;
            }

            public void setTxtaEmployeeAddress(String txtaEmployeeAddress) {
                this.txtaEmployeeAddress = txtaEmployeeAddress;
            }

            public String getRdGender() {
                return rdGender;
            }

            public void setRdGender(String rdGender) {
                this.rdGender = rdGender;
            }

            public String getSelEmployeeCountry() {
                return selEmployeeCountry;
            }

            public void setSelEmployeeCountry(String selEmployeeCountry) {
                this.selEmployeeCountry = selEmployeeCountry;
            }

            public String getChkHobby() {
                return chkHobby;
            }

            public void setChkHobby(String chkHobby) {
                this.chkHobby = chkHobby;
            }

            public boolean isHdActive() {
                return hdActive;
            }

            public void setHdActive(boolean hdActive) {
                this.hdActive = hdActive;
            }

            public Double getTxtEmployeeTotalSalary() {
                return txtEmployeeTotalSalary;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeTotalSalary(Double txtEmployeeTotalSalary) {
                this.txtEmployeeTotalSalary = txtEmployeeTotalSalary;
            }

            public Integer getTxtEmployeeIntegerValue() {
                return txtEmployeeIntegerValue;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeIntegerValue(Integer txtEmployeeIntegerValue) {
                this.txtEmployeeIntegerValue = txtEmployeeIntegerValue;
            }

            public Short getTxtEmployeeTinyIntValue() {
                return txtEmployeeTinyIntValue;
            }

            public void setTxtEmployeeTinyIntValue(Short txtEmployeeTinyIntValue) {
                this.txtEmployeeTinyIntValue = txtEmployeeTinyIntValue;
            }
        }
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

            <context:annotation-config />

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.eptl.spring4hibernate4demo.employee.*"/>

            <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

            <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">

                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.40:1433;databaseName=EmpEnc;integratedSecurity=true;columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled"/>
                <property name="username" value="abcd" />
                <property name="password" value="abc@123" />
                <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
                <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
                <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
                <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
                <property name="validationQuery" value="Select 1"/>
                <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
            </bean>

            <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                <property name="packagesToScan">
                    <list>
                        <value>com.eptl.spring4hibernate4demo.**.model</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</prop>
                        <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">5</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">16</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">25</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">8</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>

            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            </bean>

            <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" >
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
            </bean>

        </beans>
```

**Error:**

```
    > log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Hibernate: insert into Emp (hobbies, isActive, gender, country, email, emp4, emp1, Mobile, name, phone, salary, emp2, totalSalary, address) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2730)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3300)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:198)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
        at com.eptl.spring4hibernate4demo.employee.dao.AbcAbstractClass.addEntity(AbcAbstractClass.java:61)
        at com.eptl.spring4hibernate4demo.employee.daoImpl.EmployeeImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeImpl.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.addEmployee(Unknown Source)
        at com.eptl.spring4hibernate4demo.employee.service.EmployeeService.addEmployee(EmployeeService.java:22)
        at com.eptl.spring4hibernate4demo.employee.controller.EmpController.main(EmpController.java:150)
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: decimal(18,2) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'empencCEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'EmpEnc') is incompatible with decimal(18,5) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'empencCEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'EmpEnc')
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQueryInternal(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:310)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterEncryptionMetadata(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:666)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:422)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:328)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
        ... 38 more
```

**To insert Value i use Session**

```
// DaoImpl method

public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);
}

// method moves on addEmployee

@Override
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    super.addEntity(employee);
}

// and finally common class to save entity

public void addEntity(EntityType entity) {
    getCurrentSession().save(entity);
}
```

When I add decimal value into database with out encrypt column it stores in database but when I encrypt column it shows me error. I set property completely. I'm trying to add value at database side
it is inserted completely into database but when I try to insert value using hibernate it shows me an error.
What I do to insert big decimal value into always encrypted database using hibernate?

Comment: What if you do `bd.setScale(5)` before insertion?

Comment: there is still same error. I don't understand how to declare precision and scale value for always encrypted database.

Comment: And if you add `new BigDecimal("12.36001");` for testing? And In a database console can you verify that the column type is defined as `decimal(18,5)` ?

Comment: yes i already checked as database side and model i also defined. when i insert bigDecimal data into database at database side it is inserted but when i try to application side it show me error.